# How to make the numbering bold in List in iText7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext7

I am using `List` class of iText7 to create an ordered list in a PDF. The text in the `List` can be made bold easily but not the numbering. If I apply `SetBold()` to the `List` object every item added to the `List` object gets converted to bold as well. I just want to make the numbering of the ordered list in bold. How can I achieve this?

The code that I am using

```
using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(filePath)))
{
    using (Document document = new Document(pdfDocument))
    {
        List header = new List(ListNumberingType.DECIMAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.SetKeepTogether(true);

            li.Add(new Paragraph("TableName").SetFontSize(13)
                                             .SetBold());

            li.Add(new Paragraph("Hello")).SetFontSize(13);

            header.Add(li);
        }                   
        document.Add(header);
    }
}
```

The output that I am getting

[image: Screenshot of output PDF]

My desired output

[image: Screenshot of desired output PDF]

In the desired output the numbering of the list is in bold

Comment: Hi, please attach your minimal code that reproduces the issue and visual representation of the current result that would accompany your explanation of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question to include both as per your recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Java example to achieve the desired result and I hope you can easily adapt it to your programming language

```
try (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName))) {
            try (Document document = new Document(pdfDocument)) {
                List header = new List(ListNumberingType.DECIMAL);

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    ListItem li = new ListItem();
                    ListItem li2 = new ListItem();

                    li.add(new Paragraph("TableName").setFontSize(13)
                                    .setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD)))
                            .setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD));

                    li2.add(new Paragraph("Hello")).setFontSize(13)
                            .setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA));

                    li.add(li2);

                    header.add(li);
                }
                document.add(header);
            }
        }
```

My output result

[image]

Comment: This will make everything in the ```ListItem``` bold. I just want 2 make the numbering of the ```List``` in bold.

Comment: Your desired result the same as in my example

Comment: I have updated my question for better understanding of the desired result

Comment: @Suvo25 I have updated my answer. Let me know if this is your expected result.

Comment: I was able to convert the code into my programming language and it gave the desired result. Thanks